# XPS from FlowDocument Rendering bug in Images

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xps

This will be little longer post

#### Goal

Render XPS document from FlowDocument while maintaining original Images (no transformation)

#### Existing Scenarios

1. Image is added correctly (keeps format), but only first one. Cache is then broken, only 1 image is embedded in XPS and used for all images
2. All images are added and correct, but converted to PNG.

Difference occurs based on commenting / uncommenting of single line in method `GetImage` (see comments)

Minimal showcase / problem recreation code

```
Imports System.Windows.Documents
Imports System.Windows.Documents.Serialization
Imports System.Windows.Xps.Packaging
Imports System.Windows.Xps
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Packaging
Imports System.Windows.Markup
Imports System.Windows.Media.Imaging
Imports System.Windows.Media
Imports System.Windows.Controls

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Render()

    End Sub

    Sub Render()

        Using image1 = IO.File.OpenRead("image1.jpg"),
            image2 = IO.File.OpenRead("image2.png"),
            file = IO.File.Create("asdf.xps"),
            pack = Package.Open(file, FileMode.Create),
            d As New XpsDocument(pack)


            Dim writer As XpsDocumentWriter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(d)
            Dim xpsVisWriter As SerializerWriterCollator = writer.CreateVisualsCollator()

            Dim x As New FlowDocument
            x.PageWidth = 100
            x.ColumnWidth = x.PageWidth

            Dim s As New Section
            DirectCast(x, IAddChild).AddChild(s)
            s.BreakPageBefore = True

            Dim p As New Paragraph()
            DirectCast(s, IAddChild).AddChild(p)

            Dim i As New Image
            DirectCast(p, IAddChild).AddChild(i)
            i.Source = GetImage(image1)

            Dim i2 As New Image
            DirectCast(p, IAddChild).AddChild(i2)
            i2.Source = GetImage(image2)

            Dim paginator = DirectCast(x, IDocumentPaginatorSource).DocumentPaginator
            Dim pageIndex As Integer = 0

            While Not paginator.IsPageCountValid OrElse paginator.PageCount > pageIndex
                Dim page As DocumentPage = paginator.GetPage(pageIndex)


                xpsVisWriter.Write(page.Visual)
                pageIndex += 1
            End While


            xpsVisWriter.EndBatchWrite()

        End Using

    End Sub

    Function GetImage(stream As Stream) As ImageSource

        Dim result As ImageSource = BitmapFrame.Create(
            stream,
            BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat Or BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache,
            BitmapCacheOption.None)

        'If this Line Runs, scenario 2 occures, otherwise scenario 1
        'result = BitmapFrame.Create(result)

        Return result

    End Function

End Module
```

I no longer have any idea what to do with this. All possible cache enabling / disabling was tried.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done any visual basic, but I ran into similar problem with c#.  Try returning a BitmapImage instead of ImageSource in your GetImage method. [Using PngBitmapDecoder, MemoryStream, FlowDocument, XPSDocument to Preview Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415984/using-pngbitmapdecoder-memorystream-flowdocument-xpsdocument-to-preview-image)